# Moved to New Server/Ip Address Now Facebook Can't Scrape Website

Tags: facebook, apache, debugging, caching

About a week ago I moved my site to a new server and was assigned a new ip address.  After the move I was able to continue sharing content to google +, twitter etc.  Except for Facebook.  The debugger tool keeps returning the default apache page.

I've tried ever tip I've seen on this site thus far, cleared ever cache and waited a week to see if facebook would clear its caches but that hasn't happened.  All the old content made before the move and new content added after the move all return a 404 error.

http://www.awfbase.com

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you moved correctly the entire database and old settings?

Comment: yes everything is exactly as it was on the old server